# Return specific values of a dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list like:

```
list_of_list = [["aa", "yy"], ["gg", "xx"]]
```

and a pandas dataframe like this:

```
   month   column1  column2
0  June     xx        aa               
1  June     gg        xx                
2  August   xx        yy
```

I go through each sub_list of the list_of_lists and check if each item of the sub_list exists in any of the columns of the dataframe.

```
for sub_list in list_of_lists:
    print("\n")
    print("Sub_list: ", sub_list)
    for item in sub_list:
        for col in df.columns:
            if item in df[col].values:
                print(df[col][df[col] == item].to_frame())

This returns me:

Sub_list:  ['aa', 'yy']

  column2
0      aa

  column2
2      yy



Sub_list:  ["gg", "xx"]

  column1
1      gg

  column1
0      xx

  column1
2      xx

  column2
1      xx
```

What I want is except to the above to return also the index and the corresponding month when and only when, each sub_list of the list_of_lists is not in the same index

So for `list_of_list = [["aa", "yy"]]` except to the above code i want also to return

```
0  June   aa
2  August yy
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use `melt` to flat your original dataframe and create a dataframe from your `list_of_list` then merge them and finally remove duplicates in two pass.

**Step 1. Format your dataframes**

```
df1 = df.melt('month', ignore_index=False).reset_index()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list_of_list).melt(ignore_index=False)['value'].reset_index()
print(df1, df2)

# Output
# df1 (from your original df)
   index   month variable value
0      0    June  column1    xx
1      1    June  column1    gg
2      2  August  column1    xx
3      0    June  column2    aa
4      1    June  column2    xx
5      2  August  column2    yy

# df2 (from list_of_list)
   index value
0      0    aa
1      1    gg
2      0    yy
3      1    xx
```

**Step 2. Merge your two dataframes**

```
out = df1.merge(df2, on='value')
print(out)

# Output:
   index_x   month variable value  index_y
0        0    June  column1    xx        1
1        2  August  column1    xx        1
2        1    June  column2    xx        1
3        1    June  column1    gg        1
4        0    June  column2    aa        0
5        2  August  column2    yy        0
```

**Step 3. Keep only right rows**

```
out = out.drop_duplicates(subset=['index_x', 'index_y'], keep=False) \
         .drop_duplicates('value', keep=False)
print(out)

# Output:
   index_x   month variable value  index_y
4        0    June  column2    aa        0
5        2  August  column2    yy        0
```

**Step 4. Final output**

```
out = out.set_index('index_x').rename_axis(index=None)[['month', 'value']]
print(out)

# Output:
    month value
0    June    aa
2  August    yy
```

---

**Edit**
Start after step 2, create a new column `notin`:

```
out['notin'] = out.groupby('index_y')['index_x'] \
                  .transform(lambda x: len(x) == len(set(x)))
print(out)

# Output:
   index_x   month variable value  index_y  notin
0        0    June  column1    xx        1  False  # For ["gg", "xx"]
1        2  August  column1    xx        1  False
2        1    June  column2    xx        1  False
3        1    June  column1    gg        1  False
4        0    June  column2    aa        0   True  # For ["aa", "yy"]
5        2  August  column2    yy        0   True
```

From here, what is your expect output?

Comment: I updated my answer. Is it what your are looking for because I understood you only want to have an output *only when, each sub_list of the list_of_lists is not in the same index*.

Comment: yes only when each sub_list of the list_of_lists is not in the same index of my original df. Is this the case with your code? Also, is it possible to return this in a separate dataframe and the output of Sub_list:  ["gg", "xx"] in another?

Comment: if you put yy on the 1 index of column 1 the code will only return the index of aa

Comment: It's not clear for me what you really expect. I updated my answer with a new column. From this point, what do you want?

Answer (score 0):

`stack` the DataFrame and then loop through your lists:

```
df["index"] = df.index
srs = df.set_index(["index", "month"]).stack().rename("value")
for sublist in list_of_list:
    print(f"\nSub list: {sublist}")
    print(srs[srs.isin(sublist)].reset_index(2, drop=True).reset_index().drop_duplicates("index", keep=False).drop_duplicates("value", keep=False))
```

###### Inputs:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"month": ["June", "June", "August"],
                   "column1": ["xx", "gg", "xx"],
                   "column2": ["aa", "xx", "yy"]})

list_of_list = [["aa", "yy"], ["gg", "xx"]]
```

###### Output:

```
Sub list: ['aa', 'yy']
   index   month value
0      0    June    aa
1      2  August    yy

Sub list: ['gg', 'xx']
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [index, month, value]
Index: []
```

Comment: can the above code be modified to return 0  June   aa
2  August yy?

Comment: @xavi - Edited!

Comment: your code works fine but the objective is to return only the values of the list that appears in different indexes of the dataframe. In this case it should return index              
0        June    aa
2      August    yy

Is it possible to edit it? Thanks

Comment: @xavi - I edited my answer. Is that what you need?

Comment: Thank you for your effort. No i just want this to be returned Sub list: ['aa', 'yy']
   index   month value
0      0    June    aa
1      2  August    yy

Comment: @xavi - I think I understand. Re-edited. The second sub-list now prints an empty DataFrame.

Comment: how you solve this error: IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 2 levels, not 3

Comment: I don't get that error. What line is throwing it?

Comment: ok i solve the error. For this example it works fine and i should accept your aswer. However, the solution is not universal. Try to put yy on the 1 index of column 1. The code will only return the index of aa and will ignore the yy as it is duplicated I imagine. In an ideal case it must return also the yy as it is presented in the list and not ignore it

Answer (score 0):

Could use the `any` to achieve the same.

```
for sub_list in list_of_lists:
    print("\n")
    print("Sub_list: ", sub_list)
    for item in sub_list:
        print(df[(df == item).any(axis=1)])
```